# Gitlab AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, jwt, gitlab-ci, openid-connect

I'm trying to give my pipeline access to Amazon ECRs by using die Gitlab id_token feature to provide a JWT token.

My pipelines work well so far except that the aws sts command reports:

`An error occurred (InvalidIdentityToken) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Couldn't retrieve verification key from your identity provider,  please reference AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity documentation for requirements`

I tried a few things:

The URL `https://FQDN/.well-known/openid-configuration` is publicly accesible and has jwks_uri configured and the url behind that returns keys for verifiation

The URL `https://FQDN/.well-known/jwks.json` does not exist on my gitlab instance but seems to be required by the following AWS Guide: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/iam-sts-invalididentitytoken

I have no Idea what's missing or why AWS can't verify the JWT token against my gitlab instace.

Any help is appreciated thanks for reading! :D

Kind regards

Comment: In your `gitlab.rb` settings, is the configured `external_url` setting (including scheme and/or port) the same as the URL configured in the AWS IAM identity provider? Are you **sure** your GitLab instance is accessible from the _public_ internet?